# Confused by stat function

Tags: julia

I'm trying to detect whether or not a given path is a file or a directory:

```
map(stat, readdir("./"))

#=
 StatStruct(mode=040775, size=4096)
 StatStruct(mode=040775, size=4096)
=#
```

This is correct, I have two directories in my `cwd`. However, when I try to `stat` the directory:

```
map(stat, readdir("./mydir"))
```

I get

```
#=
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
 StatStruct(mode=000000, size=0)
=#
```

Which makes no sense to me at all. I have both files and folders in `mydir`. What is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at what the output of `readdir("./mydir")` is — it's *just* the filenames inside that folder, without `mydir/` prepended.  You're invoking `stat` from your current working directory with the filenames from a *different* directory.

In order for this to work, you need to either move to `mydir` or manually prepend `mydir/` to your filenames:

```
cd("./mydir") do
    map(stat, readdir())
end
```

or

```
map(f -> stat(joinpath("mydir", f)), readdir("./mydir"))
```

Comment: Does this mean `stat` can only process paths from the current directory?

Comment: No, `stat` can use absolute paths, too. But the array of strings returned by `readdir` are not absolute paths. They're just filenames without any directory information. It's not possible for `stat` to figure out that the string `"foo.txt"` actually refers to `./mydir/foo.txt`.

Comment: I see. Do you know how `cd`'s implementation manages the reference to the current directory? Can I crawl multiple directories with `cd` on one process?

Comment: It modifies the global current working directory, and then changes it back when it's done.  It's easy to test yourself: try `@async cd(()->sleep(4), "..")` and watch the value of `pwd()` change.  I'd just use the second solution if you want to concurrently process multiple directories in the same process.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that. Can you link me to a solution for processing multiple directories?

Comment: Just do it serially.  Or convert the filenames from `readdir` to absolute paths so you don't need to `cd` at all.

Comment: Thanks. If anyones interested I implemented this into a simple dirwalk: https://gist.github.com/dopatraman/6bb694e37e5f2360449e03702fe16f65